# Deno.env is not a function

Tags: javascript, deno

Working on short tutorial with `deno` and `postgres` from https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-your-first-rest-api-with-deno-and-postgres/

I had an error within my `config.js` file:

```
const env = Deno.env();

export const APP_HOST = env.APP_HOST || "127.0.0.1";
export const APP_PORT = env.APP_PORT || 4000;
```

Running deno command I got the error:

```
$ deno run -A index.js
error: Uncaught TypeError: Deno.env is not a function
const env = Deno.env();
```

Comment: Yes,  solution was just to remove brackets Deno.env()  to Deno.env   Thank you @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, [`Deno.env`](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Deno.env) isn't a function. So you don't use `()` on it. It's an object, you use it directly:

```
const env = Deno.env;
```

Answer (score 4):

That blog post is using an older version of Deno, where `Deno.env()` was a function.

It was changed for `1.0.0` release. `Deno.env` is now an object with: `.set` , `.get`, `.toObject` methods.

So to get an env variable you do:

```
Deno.env.get('MY_VARIABLE');
```

---

Deno introduced a lot of breaking changes for `1.0.0` release, so I suggest to avoid using code from tutorials using `<1.0.0`.